# Почему не бесконечный цикл?

Tags: c++, c, числа, арифметика

Почему, независимо от начального значения `i`, этот код [всегда возвращает `1`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:14,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:14,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:14,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:14,startLineNumber:4),source:%27int+main()+%7B%0A++++unsigned+char+i+%3D+42%3B%0A++++while(255+*+i%2B%2B)%7B%7D%0A++++return+i%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), а не уходит в бесконечный цикл?

```cpp
int main() {
    unsigned char i = 42;
    while(255 * i++){}
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Тут нет бесконечного цикла, он закончится, когда `i` станет 0. @andreymal Бесконечный цикл без побочных эффектов - не UB.

Comment: @user7860670 почему `i` всегда станет `0`? почему не UB?

Comment: `i` всегда станет 0 так как значение изменяется на каждой итерации. Не UB так как в стандарте не указано, что бесконечный цикл без побочных эффектов является UB.

Comment: @user7860670 наличие какого-либо изменения не доказывает, что рано или поздно станет `0`. К примеру, пусть на 1-ой итерации будет +1, а на другой -1, тогда при многих начальных `i` может не стать нулём

Comment: @stass Тут же инкремент на каждой итерации, а не +1 или -1.

Comment: @user7860670 *"Бесконечный цикл без побочных эффектов - не UB"* Интересно послушать вашу интерпретацию http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.progress-1

Comment: @HolyBlackCat В цитате по ссылке не сказано, что это является UB.

Comment: @user7860670 Это не обязательно. Если стандарт не описывает поведение программы в каком-то случае, то это автоматически UB: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.undefined Плюс, если предположить, что это таки легально, интересно, как тогда достигается *"This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops"*.

Comment: Стандарт описывает поведение программы в таком случае. Предыдущая цитата никак не запрещает бесконечные циклы и не называет их нелегальными. В ней только даются руководящие указания для реализации. *"This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops"* дополнительно поясняет мотивацию при создании реализации. Если бы они были нелегальными и поведение программы было бы не определено, то такое пояснение было бы ни к чему.

Comment: @user7860670 Я, наверное, мысль не донес. Вопрос: что разрешает компилятору убирать пустые циклы, если здесь нет UB?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ему это разрешается в явном виде в приведенном выше фрагменте. Собственно есть множество подобных ситуаций, например компилятору еще явно разрешается выкидывать вызовы функции аллокации или конструкторы. И все это в обычных условиях , а не по причине наличия какого-то UB. Собственно нет ни малейшего смысла добавлять какие-то предписания для реализации в ситуациях с UB, так как там просто может быть все, что угодно.

Comment: @user7860670 Где явно разрешается, в note? Они не имеют "юридической силы", и должны только растолковывать другие части стандарта.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я имел ввиду http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.progress-1

Comment: @user7860670 Хмм. Там написано - "implementation may assume", а как именно она может достигать этих assumptions - непонятно. Если ей для этого можно выбрасывать пустые циклы, то почему ей нельзя, например, прибить поток?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat assumptions в переводе означает "предположения", и они не достигаются, а предполагаются. И пустой цикл компилятор может выбросить не *для этого*, а *благодаря этому*. По сути там компилятору даются дополнительные возможности для облегчения анализа потока управления.

Comment: @user7860670 Наличие бесконечного цикла без наблюдаемых эффектов, порой приводит к совершенно контринтуитивным результатам, а не просто к «выбрасыванию бесконечного цикла»: [1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff57cdcd42b367cf), [2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sa6eWGf4o). `Не UB так как в стандарте не указано, что бесконечный цикл без побочных эффектов является UB` Комитет по стандартизации [считает иначе](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь

```
unsigned char i = 42;
while(255 * i++){}
```

нет никакого UB, потому что для беззнаковых типов в стандарте сказано, что всякие переполнения обрабатываются как

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer

так что достижение переменной `i` значения 0 неминуемо.

Comment: Почему неминуемо? Там же умножение есть ещё.

Comment: @stass Умножение не виляет на значение `i`

Comment: Происходит так: вычисляется значение `255*i`, запоминается, потом `i` увеличивается на 1, потом запомненное значение проверяется на ненулевость и принимается решение о выходе из цикла или очередной итерации. Именно поэтому код возвращает 1, потому что в момент принятия решения о завершении цикла `i` уже равно 1.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.